# Como copiar valores de classe para outra classe em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Protipo Software de Evento</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="demo" style="font-family:courier"></p>
<form style="background-color: gray;" action="" method="post" id="formulario">
<input  type="button" id="novoProd" value="Novo serviço" />
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="myReport()"/>
Valor total do evento é de R$
<p style="display:inline; color:yellow"id="result"></p>
<p class="demo"></p>
<div id="item" class="item">

<!-- Serviços -->
<label>Selecione o(s) serviço(s) para o seu evento:</label>
<select name="produtoId[]">
<option value="Buffet1">Buffet 1</option>
<option value="Decoração1">Decoração 1</option>
<option value="Transporte1">Transporte 1</option>
</select>

<!-- TOTAL de custos -->
<input type="number" class="qtd" onchange="myTotal()">

<!-- TOTAL de cada LINHA -->
<!-- <table style="display:inline"><th>R$</th></table> -->
<p style="display:inline" class='til'></p>
</div>

</form>
<!-- Calcula o TOTAL -->
<script>
function myTotal() {
var total = 0;
var total2 = 0;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("qtd");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
total = total + parseInt(x[i].value);
total2 = parseInt(x[i].value);
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = total;
document.getElementsByClassName("til")[0].innerHTML = total2;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#novoProd").click(function() {
var novoItem = $("#item").clone().removeAttr('id');
novoItem.children('input').val(''); //limpa o campo quantidade
$("#formulario").append(novoItem);
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

O script tenta:

Trazer o valor da classe "qtd" para "til" por CLASSE (Aqui funciona)

Como acompanhar o Array da Classe "qtd" com a CLASSE "til"?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("til").innerHTML` isso não vai funcionar porque o `getElementsByClassName` retorna um `HTMLCollection` que é tipo um `Array`

Comment: O código tá todo errado, clonando elementos com id. Não pode duplicar id's

Comment: Pronto @Sam, não está mais copiando ID's

Comment: Por que vc usa id e fez uma gambiarra pra remover o atributo no script? rs...

Comment: A gente só usa id quando um elemento é único, e olha que nem isso. Mesmo o elemento sendo único o que vejo por aí é usar class.

Comment: @Sam, uso ID somente para calcular o total que é visualizado no topo, ele é único e não se repete.

As linhas se repetem, logo tenho que receber o valor em array da classe "qtd" do input e retornar ao lado para a classe "til" da tag <p>

Comment: Mas não precisa de id se vc tem uma classe no mesmo elemento. Se vc quer pegar o primeiro elemento com a classe basta fazer `$(".item")`, ou `$(".item:eq(0)"`... pra q colocar id e depois remover no clone?... precisa disso não meu jovem

Comment: Também tá fazendo uma mistureba de JS puro com jQuery rs.. Já que vc pagou 80KB pra usar jQuery, faz tudo em jQuery mesmo. :)

Comment: Falta também indentar o código, fica confuso de entender. Boa sorte aí!

Comment: @Sam, encontrei
 `<input type="number" class="qtd" id="on" onchange="myTotal()">`
retirei, pois estava utilizando em outras funções teste.
Versão atual é 
`<input type="number" class="qtd" onchange="myTotal()">`

Comment: Não mude o título da pergunta colocando (resolvido)... se foi resolvido vc deve marcar uma resposta com ✔, como já fez. Todo mundo saberá que foi resolvido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `getElementsByClassName` como o nome diz retorna `Elements` ou seja uma especie de `Array` chamada [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

No seu código você esta trantando como um `HTMLElement` (*tentando acessar `.innerHTML`*) quando na verdade e uma 'array' de `HTMLElements`

Possível solução: `document.getElementsByClassName("til")[0].innerHTML`

Outra coisa que notei é que você 'escrevendo' o valor no `HTML` enquanto ainda calcula, ou seja, dentro do `for`

```
function myTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    var total2 = 0;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("qtd");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        total = total + parseInt(x[i].value);
        total2 = parseInt(x[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = total;
    document.getElementsByClassName("til")[0].innerHTML = total2;
}
```